# I updated to 10.9.2 and now SSL is broken. How do I fix this?

Tags: macos, ssl

As per the title, I upgraded my Mac to Mavericks 10.9.2, and now a bunch of websites which use SSL (aka https) don't work!

[image]

What do I do?

Comment: You can try this solution too: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/174749/116419.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Keychain Access and delete the DigiCert certificates, but **only the ones in the `login` keychain** - not the ones in `System` or `System Roots`.

Afterward, you may need to restart your browser and/or network service (switch Airport off and on again, or disable and re-enable Ethernet. If you want to [be sure](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCbfMkh940Q), just restart your computer.

If you're a dummy (like I was) and deleted *all* the DigiCert entries, you can restore them by [manually downloading and installing the 10.9.2 update from Apple.](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1726)

Comment: I can confirm that this worked for me.